# Executing an unused lambda expression in debug session throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, classnotfoundexception

This is a bit nitpicky- I wonder if it's a bug or a feature:

I have this main in Intellij:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Comparator<String> comp = (s1,s2) ->  1;
    System.out.println("Break here");
 }
```

When I debug and break at the "System.out.." I see that *comp* is initialized. However, when I try to execute it from "Expression Evaluation" window I get a ClassNotFoundException!

Of course evaluating the same thing in code works perfectly. Is it somehow related to the way lambdas are implemented under the hood or just a bug in the IDE?

I am using Intellij 13.1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluation of Lambda expressions is supported only starting from version 14.

Taken from [What's New in IntelliJ IDEA 14 page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/):

[image]